# Google Custom Search inconsistent feedback

Tags: date-range, google-custom-search

I've been making the same request repeatedly and each time i get a different feedback.
I'm trying to get the total appearances of a certain term (in this case: bigdata) by making 2 requests trough **'dateRestrict'** and subtracting the "totalResults" I get from the response Json and even thou i do not change anything, it always gives me something like:

first time I run it:

- **LowerRange** total: 6710000
- **UpperRange** total: 6760000

next time:

- **LowerRange** total: 6720000
- **UpperRange** total: 6770000

and the next:

- **LowerRange** total: 6740000
- **UpperRange** total: 6760000

---

- **LowerRange**: 1 March.
- **UpperRange**: 1 January.

everything pretty close, but different still.
Any insights on why this is happening? I'm not so familiar with how this response is made, so it might be right and I am misunderstanding.

my request for march is this:https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q=bigdata&dateRestrict=d144&key=MY_API_KEY&cx=MY_UNIQUE_KEY

Another doubt i have is if the API rounds the results, cause I never get something like 6740107.

Answer (score 0):

Based on its' searching algorithm, It provides different results to user. If you search a particular item in Google search, It will provide different output every time based on users, location, time etc. It is the beauty of Google Search. Go through the [link](http://themetaq.com/articles/reasons-your-google-search-results-are-different-than-mine) for your reference.